# Need to get list of all dates in a particular month

Tags: php

if i just give input ex: Jan i need to get all dates in Jan

```
2013-01-01
2013-01-07
....
...
2013-07-31
```

Can anyone suggest me with any formula or code will be helpfull

Comment: you should have searched regarding this, go for date function in php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$totalDays = date('t');    
for( $i=1; $i<= $totalDays; $i++)
 $dates[]= date('Y') . "-". date('m'). "-". str_pad($i,2,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
var_dump($dates);
```